# RHEL 8 - Unable to complete pyPDF2 offline installation due to typing_extensions

Tags: python, unix, offline, pypdf, rhel8

I've been stuck with this problem.
I work on a UNIX RHEL8 server which did not allow to access internet.

All required packages and modules I able to install expect this pyPDF2 module due to typing_extensions

- RHEL8 Python 3.6.8
- Pip 9.0.3 installed but not able to use due to no internet access
- PyPDF2 2.10.0 try to install using `python setup.py build && python setup.py install`

```
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2-2.10.0-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for PyPDF2==2.10.0
Searching for typing_extensions
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/typing_extensions/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/typing_extensions/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/typing-extensions/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/typing-extensions/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldnt find index page for 'typing_extensions' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for typing_extensions
```

`pip install` method unable to be use due to no internet access

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Try installing the package before pyPDF2 with `pip install typing-extensions`

Comment: Cannot use pip due to no internet access

Comment: If you don't have an internet connection, how do you use stack overflow?

Comment: If you don't have an internet connection, you need to fix it yourself. You can edit PyPDF2 to remove the typing extension dependency. Nothing will break

Comment: I just have to read my question slowly my friend. The server I working on dont have internet access. My pc here got internet access. That how I use stackoverflow.

Comment: How to close this question? Ive fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package:

```
pip install typing-extensions
```

In newer Python versions that package is not required.

You can also edit the source of PyPDF2 to remove all imports of it and Literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can download whl file from https://pypi.org/ for the package.
And if pip is installed it can be easily installed using :

pip install wheel_file.whl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).